# What is the difference between maven.plugin.classpath and maven.runtime.classpath

Tags: java, maven, classpath

Maven recognizes 4 classpaths:

- maven.compile.classpath:
  Classes and jars which need to be on classpath when compiling your source codes. So basically for maven-compiler-plugin
- maven.test.classpath: Classes and jars which need to be on classpath when running unit tests or integration tests
- maven.runtime.classpath:
  I understood that maven.runtime.classpath contains jars and classes maven itself needs to run.
- maven.plugin.classpath:
  I understood that this classpath is pass to maven plugin when the plugin runs it's own JVM

Questions:

- Am I right?
- Is plugin superset of compile classpath?
- Is test superset of compile classpath?
- When plugin runs it's own JVM - what is the
  classpath passed to it?
- Is there any documentation on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, you have it wrong, but I couldn't find any documentation stating this explicitly.

Those 4 properties are defined by the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) and are not part of Maven itself. From [Referencing the Maven Classpaths](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html):

> You can also use these classpath references:
>
> - `maven.compile.classpath`
> - `maven.runtime.classpath`
> - `maven.test.classpath`
> - `maven.plugin.classpath`

This plugin creates those 4 properties so that Ant tasks can refer to them. You'll find where those properties are created if you take a look [at the source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-plugins/blob/trunk/maven-antrun-plugin/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/antrun/AntRunMojo.java#L279-L295), copied here for reference

> ```
> Path p = new Path( antProject );
> p.setPath( StringUtils.join( mavenProject.getCompileClasspathElements().iterator(), File.pathSeparator ) );
>
> /* maven.dependency.classpath it's deprecated as it's equal to maven.compile.classpath */
> antProject.addReference( "maven.dependency.classpath", p );
> antProject.addReference( "maven.compile.classpath", p );
>
> p = new Path( antProject );
> p.setPath( StringUtils.join( mavenProject.getRuntimeClasspathElements().iterator(), File.pathSeparator ) );
> antProject.addReference( "maven.runtime.classpath", p );
>
> p = new Path( antProject );
> p.setPath( StringUtils.join( mavenProject.getTestClasspathElements().iterator(), File.pathSeparator) );
> antProject.addReference( "maven.test.classpath", p );
>
> /* set maven.plugin.classpath with plugin dependencies */
> antProject.addReference( "maven.plugin.classpath", getPathFromArtifacts( pluginArtifacts, antProject ) );
> ```

By analyzing this code, it is possible to conclude that:

- `maven.compile.classpath` corresponds to elements of the classpath that are of scope `compile`.
- `maven.runtime.classpath` corresponds to elements of the classpath that are of scope `runtime`.
- `maven.test.classpath` corresponds to elements of the classpath that are of scope `test`.
- `maven.plugin.classpath` corresponds to the dependencies of the `maven-antrun-plugin` itself.