# run a java application and a web application in a single maven build within a reactor project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build-process

I have a reactor project with the following structure

```
server
- pom.xml (parent) 
-- appserver (has a server socket)
-- webserver (connects to the socket in appserver and gets data)
```

The appserver `pom.xml` has a `maven-exec-plugin` that runs the main method in my java class `AppServer`.

When I run goal verify in my topmost (server) project my build gets stuck at appserver - exec goal and never proceeds to building / running my webserver.

Ideally I would like to run my appserver first and then my webserver in a single install or verify run on my top most project.

Here is the exec maven plugin configuration in my appserver pom.

```xml
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
<executions> 
  <execution> 
    <goals> 
      <goal>java</goal> 
    </goals> 
  </execution> 
</executions> 
<configuration> 
  <mainClass>somepackage.AppServer</mainClass> 
</configuration>
```

I am aware that many other questions of similar nature have been asked before and most answers revolve around use of shell scripts with antrun plugin and almost all of them atleast 3 / 4 years old and I hope there is new solution in a more platform independent manner available now.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your problem. What do you want to do here? Could you tell us what your project is about, what it's supposed to do, and what it's not doing?

Comment: When I run mvn verify on topmost project my build process gets stuck at running my java class in my AppServer as it is a blocking process. I would like the build to continue and run my webserver afterwards.

Comment: Ha, you'll have more luck with the [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html) goal (instead of `java`). It executes in a forked VM. You can make it call a shell script that starts a background process. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/27804862/1743880

Comment: @Tunaki I am on windows and my CI is on linux.. I am afraid this is not a solution for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are unfortunately no better solutions than using the `maven-antrun-plugin` for your use-case. [`maven-exec-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) can be used to launch an external process, either in the same VM with the [`java`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html) goal or in a forked VM with the [`exec`](http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) goal, but in both cases, it will be blocking; meaning that the plugin will wait for the execution to finish. The possible work-around of starting a Shell script as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9937402/1743880) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27804862/1743880) works well in Linux environment. It won't work in your case however because you need to support multiple environments.

With the [`maven-antrun-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/), you can use the [Exec](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task and set the `spawn` attribute to `true`. This will cause Ant to run the task in the background. A sample configuration would be:

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.8</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase> <!-- a lifecycle phase --> </phase>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
          <exec executable="java" spawn="true">
            <arg value="-classpath"/>
            <arg value="${runtime_classpath}"/>
            <arg value="somepackage.AppServer"/>
          </exec>  
        </target>
      </configuration>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note that this uses the [`maven.runtime.classpath`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/examples/classpaths.html) to refer to the Maven classpath containing all runtime dependencies (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903281/1743880) for more info).

Comment: Precise.. very Precise :) hooked it to verify phase and it worked like a charm and I believe its platform independent as well which is the bonus I need.