# Gracefully stopping a java process started by maven-antrun-plugin

Tags: java, maven, kill-process, maven-antrun-plugin

This question is a result of an answer to this question from yesterday

[run a java application and a web application in a single maven build within a reactor project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437358/run-a-java-application-and-a-web-application-in-a-single-maven-build-within-a-re/35437896#35437896)

So as answered in the above question I now have a maven-antrun-plugin that forks a child process and runs my java appserver using a configuration like this -

```xml
<plugin>
<artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.8</version>
<executions>
<execution>
  <phase> verify </phase>
  <configuration>
    <target>
      <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
      <exec executable="java" spawn="true">
        <arg value="-classpath"/>
        <arg value="${runtime_classpath}"/>
        <arg value="somepackage.AppServer"/>
      </exec>  
    </target>
  </configuration>
  <goals>
    <goal>run</goal>
  </goals>
</execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The above configuration smoothly starts my appserver as a background process.

Now my question is if there is an easy way I can locate this process and stop it if I need after I start it through my build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`jps`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html) utility that is bundled inside the JDK to get the process ID of a running Java executable:

> The `jps` tool lists the instrumented HotSpot Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system. The tool is limited to reporting information on JVMs for which it has the access permissions.

Then, when we have retrieved the process ID, we can kill it using [`taskkill`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725602%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) on Windows or `kill` or Unix system.

This would be a sample configuration of the `maven-antrun-plugin`. It declares the `jps` executable and redirect the result of its invocation in the property `process.pid` with the [`<redirector>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/redirector.html) attribute. The result is filtered with [`<outputfilterchain>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html) so that only the lines corresponding to the executable `AppServer` are kept. `jps` output is in the form `[PID] [NAME]` so the name is then removed with [`<replacestring>`](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#replacestring); this way, we only keep the PID. Finally, there are two `exec` configuration depending on the OS.

```xml
<configuration>
    <target>
        <property name="runtime_classpath" refid="maven.runtime.classpath" />
        <exec executable="java" spawn="true">
            <arg value="-classpath" />
            <arg value="${runtime_classpath}" />
            <arg value="somepackage.AppServer" />
        </exec>
        <exec executable="${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jps">
            <arg value="-l" />
            <redirector outputproperty="process.pid">
                <outputfilterchain>
                    <linecontains>
                        <contains value="somepackage.AppServer" />
                    </linecontains>
                    <replacestring from=" somepackage.AppServer" />
                </outputfilterchain>
            </redirector>
        </exec>
        <exec executable="taskkill" osfamily="winnt">
            <arg value="/PID" />
            <arg value="${process.pid}" />
        </exec>
        <exec executable="kill" osfamily="unix">
            <arg value="-15" />
            <arg value="${process.pid}" />
        </exec>
    </target>
</configuration>
```

Since you mentioned "gracefully", I used the `-15` option on Unix and didn't include the `/F` option for Windows. If you want to force the exit, you can use `kill -9` on the Unix system and add the `/F` option on Windows.

Comment: If this works .. would be quite impressive.. Can you confirm it works with you ? I am going to try it now :)

Comment: @Gautam Yep I tested by launching a Java class that ran `while(true);` and it killed it properly :).

Answer (score 3):

Having tried various options, I've found that the process-exec-maven-plugin to be best. I realize that the OP is asking about maven-antrun-plugin specifically but that is because of an answer received to a generic question.

https://github.com/bazaarvoice/maven-process-plugin

An example of using it to start a nodeJs server which is used as part of integration tests:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.bazaarvoice.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>process-exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${process-exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <!-- Start process -->
        <execution>
            <id>node-server</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <name>node-server</name>
                <workingDir>../../test-server-dir</workingDir>
                <waitForInterrupt>false</waitForInterrupt>
                <healthcheckUrl>http://localhost:3000/</healthcheckUrl>
                <arguments>
                    <argument>node</argument>
                    <argument>./app.js</argument>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <!--Stop all processes in reverse order-->
        <execution>
            <id>stop-all</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop-all</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```